# 3-rd party tile doesn't load in Google Map

Tags: java, android, google-maps, openstreetmap

I developing simple Android application which used Google Map API and a part of the functionality is possibility to change map(tile) provider dynamically(ex. change tile between Google Map and Open Street Map tile). I'm trying to use Google Map TileProvider but instead OSM tile I see nothing(like tile doesn't load). If picked provider is Google everything works fine.

Next piece of code illustrates how it implemented :

```
    mapView = (MapView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.map);
    mapView.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    try {
        MapsInitializer.initialize(getActivity().getApplicationContext());
    } catch (Exception e) {
        logger.error("Error occurs while map initializing");
    }

    mapView.onResume(); 

    mapView.getMapAsync(new OnMapReadyCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap) {
           mMap = googleMap;
           if (MapProvider.valueOf(LocalPreferenceManager.getMapProvider(getContext())) != MapProvider.Google) {

                final String osmUrl = "http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png";
                TileProvider tileProvider = new UrlTileProvider(256,256) {

                    @Override
                    public URL getTileUrl(int x, int y, int zoom) {
                        URL url = null;
                        try {
                            String s = String.format(osmUrl,zoom, x, y);
                            url = new URL(s);
                        } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                        return url;
                    }
                };
                mMap.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_NONE);
                mMap.addTileOverlay(new TileOverlayOptions().
                        tileProvider(tileProvider));
            }
            //some action...
        }
    });
```

I'd appreciate any help.

Comment: Check if the url, you are trying to load is the correct one by: String url = osmUrl.replace("{z}", "" + zoom).replace("{x}", "" + x).replace("{y}", "" + y);
Log.w(YourClass.class.getSimpleName(), "Url is " + url);
return new URL(url);

Comment: @jantursky, everything correct I've checked one more time, simplified code a bit

Comment: I think, that your should inspire by this [source code here](https://github.com/googlemaps/android-samples/blob/master/ApiDemos/java/app/src/main/java/com/example/mapdemo/TileOverlayDemoActivity.java). And switch from MapView to MapFragment or SupportMapFragment.

Answer (score 1):

"http://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png" is no longer valid since a couple of days ago.  Try "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/%d/%d/%d.png".

Whilst it'd be nice if things did redirect automatically, not every client does.

Answer (score 1):

Seems that OSM tile server requires non-empty "User-Agent" header, otherwise it fails with HTTP code 403.

I didn't find a way to set User-agent via URL in the getTileUrl, and had to implement my own TileProvider with code like that

```
URL url = getTileUrl(x, y, z);
if (url != null) {
   URLConnection conn = url.openConnection();
   conn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent", "any string?");
   ..........
}
```